# "Npm Start" Is Not Working

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, web, npm-start

I'm in the middle of making a website, and I use the command `npm start` to put it up on localhost. However, all of a sudden it stopped working after I had created two workspaces on Visual Studio Code Editor. It only gives me an error.

This is what the error looks like:

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\audre\first-blog\package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -4058
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\audre\first-blog\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!      C:\Users\audre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-05-29T07_42_13_915Z-debug.log

I have no idea what that means. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Edit:
My package.json file contains the following:

```html
{
  "name": "pug-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple pug (jade) starter [framework] enabling faster delivery of HTML & CSS projects to a private server and/or automatic deployment of GitHub pages.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp dev",
    "start": "gulp dev",
    "prod": "gulp build --production",
    "deploy": "gulp build --production && gulp deploy && gulp clean:ghpages",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "//": "CUSTOM CONFIGURATION",
  "config": {
    "directory": {
      "development": "tmp",
      "production": "build",
      "ghpages": ".publish",
      "source": "src",
      "data": "_data",
      "component": "_component",
      "layout": "_layout",
      "asset": "_asset",
      "image": "image",
      "font": "font",
      "templateCollection": [
        "article",
        "product"
      ]
    },
    "render": {
      "sourceFileChange": false,
      "url": {
        "//": "this is recommended to avoid Linux/Windows capitalization issue",
        "htmlExtensionOn": false,
        "toLowercase": true
      }
    },
    "entry": {
      "cssExternal": "style**.{scss,sass}",
      "cssInline": "inline**.{scss,sass}",
      "css": {
        "inline": false,
        "external": true
      }
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/marianzburlea/pug-starter.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "pug",
    "starter",
    "jade",
    "starter"
  ],
  "author": "Marian Zburlea",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/marianzburlea/pug-starter/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/marianzburlea/pug-starter#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "eslint": "^3.16.1",
    "foldero": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-changed-in-place": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-gh-pages": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-inline-source": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.3.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "imagemin-jpegoptim": "^5.0.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^5.2.0",
    "jstransformer-markdown-it": "^2.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\audre\first-blog\package.json` exist on your machine?

Comment: What's the content of the debug logfile?

Comment: I think so. I've got a file that's labeled, "package.json," if that's what you mean, tbrk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails, remove/reinstall node.js completely. When you get wild errors all over the board on all of your node env commands, it means node is corrupted or wrong in some way.

Comment: Okay, that worked for me. I should have thought of that before. :)
Thank you very much, @LAdams87!

Comment: I thought I was going crazy reading about all of these technologies I wasn't using getting the same error! I've been trying to spread this answer like wildfire. I've found a ton of highly ranked answers that it applies to! My powers are weak, however.

Comment: Oh, well. I'm glad that you stopped by to share this! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a process manager that will take care of environment.

few options are

**forever**(https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

with this, you start the website on localhost using `forever start <mainfilename>`

**PM2** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

with this, you start the website on localhost using `pm2 start <mainfilename>`

With process managers, you are abstracted from the environment specifications until you need to have something more specific.

Comment: Hi, harshvardhan! Thanks for your answer

Comment: I decided to install the Forever program, and then I typed in the forever start command. However, it gives me: bash:syntax error near unexpected token `newline`. What do I do about that? Thank you again.

Comment: please post the exact line that you entered and also the trace of the error

Comment: The line that I entered is:
`forever start <first-blog>`

The error that I got was:
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`

Comment: Oh....You dont have to put the braces :)
so you command goes:

forever start first-blog

Comment: Have you installed forever? Your command should be something like 'npm install forever' or 'npm i forever'

Comment: I got another error after typing in, `npm i forever`.

Comment: Please follow installation instructions on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Okay, @harshvardhan. Thank you for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT means, where you are running `npm start` command that directory does not contain package.json file.

First, make sure you are in the correct directory and it has package.json file.

Also, if there is no package.json file, you can initialize it using `npm init` command.

If this is not the case, feel free to drop comments to correct me.

Comment: Hi, @CaptainJackSparrow! 
I do have a package.json file and it is in the same directory.

Comment: you can try this command ``npm i -g npm@latest`` once and then try again with your ``npm start``.

Comment: Can you post content of your package.json

Comment: Okay. However, there aren't enough characters in it. (You know, the limited supply of letters you're able to use in a comment.) Unless I update my post, which I'll do now.

Comment: How many lines do you want of the package.json file? It's a very long file.

Comment: scripts connection.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: SOrry I meant, Scripts section.

Comment: Before, `npm start` was running smoothly and I had no problem with the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of nodejs on your machine and are running node version manager (nvm), be sure to set your version correctly in terminal.

ex.
nvm use v9.5.0